# Laravel | What is the correct way to send a reminder email exactly 1 hour before a start time?

Tags: php, laravel, scheduling

I have a meeting table with a start_time field, i want to send an email exactly 1 hour before the start time, making sure that every new meeting is scheduled too.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to run a scheduled job that can get relevant meetings at the right time and dispatch them.

```php
Meeting::where('start_time', now()->addHour()->format('H:i'))
    ->each(fn ($meeting) => ...);
```